# how show size attribute like button format instead of drop down in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

**how show size attribute like button format instead of drop down in magento**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are free extension available in magentocommerce.

[Product Custom Option Plus with Option Swatches](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-custom-option-plus-with-option-swatches.html)

you can find many but above one is available with positive reviews.